# Select from where ID in (an array of my program)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net, ms-access

I want to get a list of items from my table based on it ID. Which the list of ID i need to select is contain in an array or dictionary in my program.

So instead of using a lot of query :

> Select * from tblData where ID=1
>
> Select * from tblData where ID=3
>
> Select * from tblData where ID=9
>
> Select * from tblData where ID=15
>
> ... ( thousand of records here) Select * from tblData where ID=50000
>
> Select * from tblData where ID=50100

It's very worse for performance because of to many query need to be run. Is there any other smarter way to do this ?

Comment: Use sql join to get batter performance.

Comment: do you have this particular list on a different table?

Comment: @Angel_Boy no, it's just stored in an array of my program. Because users select which record to show from my program by highlight it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `In` in `Where` condition.

```
Dim sIDs As String
For Each sID As String In dic.Keys
    sIDs += sID + ","
Next

'Remove last comma
sIDs = sIDs.Substring(0,sIDs.Length-1)

Dim sql As String = "Select * from tblData where ID In (" + sIDs + ")"
```

now you can execute this sql and fill datatable using sql adapter

if the values are stored in Array then you can use String.Join and place it in sql query with in statement.

```
Dim sIDs As String = String.Join(",", arrID)
Dim sql As String = "Select * from tblData where ID In (" + sIDs + ")"
```

Comment: Is one line `For Each` valid vb.net code? Or closing `Next` need to be added

Comment: thanks to point out the correction @Fabio. Next needs to be added.

Comment: @Nimesh thank you for your answer, it took me about 8 second for select 17000 item with your solution. If i select all table and than compare with dictionary it just took 3 second. So your answer is not better now.

Comment: are you using dictionary or array?

Comment: it is also depending upon your data structure. what type of indexes you have created on ur table and what method do you use currently. please mention in your question.

Comment: @Nimesh I have a list of ID stored in my program (i can store it either dictionary or array if you want one of them). And i finding the fastest way to select all item that have the same ID in my database. Your solution is join them into one query, i try it with 17000 record and it took 8 second. However, if i select * from table and than using a loop to compare and remove in-needed item, it took me just 3 second.

Comment: @Nimesh I already have a primary key index for ID column. The table just contain few column like FirstName, LastName, Email... for testing

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Select *` but using the explicit columns instead `Select Column1, Column2` ...

Depending on your table/db structure and data you might gain some speed trying a different solution:

1. Select all your records using a `WHERE ID BETWEEN min_sId AND max_sId` (so you have a limiting filter on the Ids) and then exclude the ones you don't need. (I'd probably use this solution)
2. Use a temporary table where you first insert your Ids and then select from your tblData using an `INNER JOIN` on your temporary table (I don't think it'll be faster since you need to insert all your ids in the table before joining)

I'd also consider changing the logic of my interface, if my user can select 50.000 elements something doesn't sound quite right.